# Add a class to the html element using angular js dynamically on the basis of If condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am implementing some default styles for a div for a "condition id" as (id="default")

```
<div id="student" class="student"> /* if(id == "default") */
```

I need to set some other styles (class="changeStyle"), if the "condition id" is changed i.e. (id != "default")

```
<div id="student" class="changeStyle"> /*if(id != "default") */
```

which should be added dynamically, if it's finding the (id != "default").

Any suggesstion/example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

*Example*: Here assuming ID is a variable in scope

```
<div 
  ng-class="{'changeStyle': id != 'default',  'student': id == 'default'}">
```